# System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Home Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (MvcDB dataBase = new MvcDB())
    {

    }
    return View();
}

public void DataDoldur()
{
    using (MvcDB dataBase = new MvcDB())
    {
        Kategori ktgr1 = new Kategori();
        ktgr1.KategoriAdi = "Spor";
        dataBase.Kategori.Add(ktgr1);

        dataBase.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <div>
            <label>Kategori Seçiniz:</label>
        </div>
        <select name="Seçilen Kategori">
            @foreach (Kategori kategori in Model)
            {
               <option>@kategori.KategoriAdi</option> 
            }
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Haberleri Listele " />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

"System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null" error I get it. what should I do? My database is ready but I cant use it. I think it is true, but does not work. 
How can I get the foreach to work? Not understanding this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Welcome to the community. The error is because you haven't defined Model in your View.

Try the following :
a) create a `_Layout.cshtml` file - it's like a master file under Views/Shared folder.

b) Put all your HTML in the layout and in the view files - have only the code that you need in the body.

c) Send a model from your get controller method.

d) Receive the model in your View and iterate in `foreach` (or) build a dropdown using HTML Helper

_Layout.cshtml :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
   @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml :

```
@model <Your Model >
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} 
  <div> 
      <div>
         <label>Kategori Seçiniz:</label>
      </div>
      <select name="Seçilen Kategori"> // Instead of using it this way, please go with @Html.DropDownListFor
                @foreach (Kategori kategori in Model)
                {
                   <option>@kategori.KategoriAdi</option> 
                }
       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Haberleri Listele " />
   </div>
```

Home Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (MvcDB dataBase = new MvcDB())
    {

    }
    return View(< YourModel > );
}
```

You need to fill your model and send it to the View like above .

Answer (score 0):

you could use `@model List<your model>` in your Index page.